# Remove double quotes from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to remove double quotes from array in JavaScript?

my data, this polygon coordinates google maps

```
["{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.1782636642456}", "{lat:-8.087867882261257,lng:112.17800617218018}", "{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}"]
```

to

```
[{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}, {lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.15251445770264}, {lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.1782636642456}, {lat:-8.087867882261257,lng:112.17800617218018}, {lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}]
```

after remove double quotes my data must be still array, not string.

Thanks

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think you should fix this at the source, not in JavaScript.

Comment: That looks like almost-JSON in an array. How did it get that way in the first place?

Comment: Try this `arr = arr.map(function(item) { return JSON.parse(item) })`

Comment: @Kishan That's not JSON.

Comment: Try `var objCoordinates = JSON.parse(jsonCoordinates);` where `jsonCoordinates` is your string, as it looks like json to me (or at least close enough), other than that you can't, since arrays in javascript only takes numbers as values for keys, if you need strings you'll have to use objects.

Comment: As per your question, it's array of string and each string is a JSON which is converted to string

Comment: If this is fully string then you can try `arr = JSON.parse(arr).map(function(item) { return JSON.parse(item) })`

Comment: @KishanMundha The strings aren't JSON because the keys aren't wrapped in quotes. The answer to the question is to fix whatever generated the original Object.

Comment: my data is initially a string then i want to convert to array without double quotes

Comment: Is this work `arr.map(function(item) { var match = item.match(/lat:(\-?[0-9\.]+),lng:(\-?[0-9\.]+)/); return {lat: match[1], lng: match[2]} })`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't alter the results you get above, you have to work around it.

```js
var a = ["{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.1782636642456}", "{lat:-8.087867882261257,lng:112.17800617218018}", "{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}"];

a = a.map(function(o){

  var d = o.split(',').map(function(b){
      return Number( b.replace(/(}|{lat:|lng:)/g, '') );

            /* OR  
             b.replace('{lat:', '')
              .replace('lng:', '')
              .replace('}', '');
            */

  });
  
  return {
     lat: d[0],
     lng: d[1]
  };
  
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: I try this, and there are still double quotes, 
{lat: "-8.089057558100306", lng: "112.15251445770264"} how to remove double quotes?

Comment: @MuhammadAziiz, check your browser console. The snippet console shows it as JSON.

Comment: how to change to {lat: -8.089057558100306, lng: 112.15251445770264} ? without double quotes

Answer (score 1):

*Iif* you really trust that data, `eval`ing it is the simplest way to convert it:

```js
let data = ["{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.1782636642456}", "{lat:-8.087867882261257,lng:112.17800617218018}", "{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}"];

console.log(data.map(s => eval('null,' + s)));
```

*(The `null,` is just there to make `eval` treat this as an expression instead of a `{` block `}`.)*

However, as always, `eval` can introduce code injection vulnerabilities if you're not sure about where the data comes from. And really, you should figure out how the data got this way in the first place and fix it up into a useful format there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex

```js
var arr = ["{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.15251445770264}", "{lat:-8.100954123313068,lng:112.1782636642456}", "{lat:-8.087867882261257,lng:112.17800617218018}", "{lat:-8.089057558100306,lng:112.15251445770264}"]

arr = arr.map(function(item) {
  var match = item.match(/lat:(\-?[0-9\.]+),lng:(\-?[0-9\.]+)/);
  return {lat: +match[1], lng: +match[2]};
})

console.log(arr)
```